# WPF: Cancel a user selection in a databound ListBox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

How do I cancel a user selection in a databound WPF ListBox? The source property is set correctly, but the ListBox selection is out of sync.

I have an MVVM app that needs to cancel a user selection in a WPF ListBox if certain validation conditions fail. Validation is triggered by a selection in the ListBox, rather than by a Submit button.

The `ListBox.SelectedItem` property is bound to a `ViewModel.CurrentDocument` property. If validation fails, the setter for the view model property exits without changing the property. So, the property to which `ListBox.SelectedItem` is bound doesn't get changed.

If that happens, the view model property setter does raise the PropertyChanged event before it exits, which I had assumed would be enough to reset the ListBox back to the old selection. But that's not working--the ListBox still shows the new user selection. I need to override that selection and get it back in sync with the source property.

Just in case that's not clear, here is an example: The ListBox has two items, Document1 and Document2; Document1 is selected. The user selects Document2, but Document1 fails to validate. The `ViewModel.CurrentDocument` property is still set to Document1, but the ListBox shows that Document2 is selected. I need to get the ListBox selection back to Document1.

Here is my ListBox Binding:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResults, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentDocument, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I did try using a callback from the ViewModel (as an event) to the View (which subscribes to the event), to force the SelectedItem property back to the old selection. I pass the old Document with the event, and it is the correct one (the old selection), but the ListBox selection doesn't change back.

So, how do I get the ListBox selection back in sync with the view model property to which its `SelectedItem` property is bound? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the 'SearchResults' collection change at any point after the control is created?  I think there can be a problem with the collection that the ItemsSource is bound to changes at any time or when the SelectedItem object comes from a different collection.

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608071/wpf-cancel-a-user-selection-in-a-databound-listbox which has more answers, including the one that links to http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/04/25/cancelling-selection-change-in-a-bound-wpf-combo-box.aspx

Comment: See my answer below for a simple XAML solution in .NET 4.5+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

-snip-

Well forget what I wrote above.

I just did an experiment, and indeed SelectedItem goes out of sync whenever you do anything more fancy in the setter. I guess you need to wait for the setter to return, and then change the property back in your ViewModel asynchronously.

Quick and dirty working solution (tested in my simple project) using MVVM Light helpers:
In your setter, to revert to previous value of CurrentDocument

```
                var dp = DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher;
                if (dp != null)
                    dp.BeginInvoke(
                    (new Action(() => {
                        currentDocument = previousDocument;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentDocument");
                    })), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

it basically queues the property change on the UI thread, ContextIdle priority will ensure it will wait for UI to be in consistent state. it Appears you cannot freely change dependency properties while inside event handlers in WPF.

Unfortunately it creates coupling between your view model and your view and it's an ugly hack.

To make DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher work you need to do DispatcherHelper.Initialize() first.

Comment: More elegant solution would be to add a IsCurrentDocumentValid property or just a Validate() method on the viewmodel and use it in the view to allow or disallow selection change.

Answer (score 47):

For future stumblers on this question, this page is what ultimately worked for me: 
http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/04/25/cancelling-selection-change-in-a-bound-wpf-combo-box.aspx

It's for a combobox, but works for a listbox just fine, since in MVVM you don't really care what type of control is calling the setter. The glorious secret, as the author mentions, is to ***actually change the underlying value and then change it back.* It was also important to run this “undo” on a separate dispatcher operation.**

```c#
private Person _CurrentPersonCancellable;
public Person CurrentPersonCancellable
{
    get
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Getting CurrentPersonCancellable.");
        return _CurrentPersonCancellable;
    }
    set
    {
        // Store the current value so that we can 
        // change it back if needed.
        var origValue = _CurrentPersonCancellable;

        // If the value hasn't changed, don't do anything.
        if (value == _CurrentPersonCancellable)
            return;

        // Note that we actually change the value for now.
        // This is necessary because WPF seems to query the 
        //  value after the change. The combo box
        // likes to know that the value did change.
        _CurrentPersonCancellable = value;

        if (
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Allow change of selected item?", 
                "Continue", 
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo
            ) != MessageBoxResult.Yes
        )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Selection Cancelled.");

            // change the value back, but do so after the 
            // UI has finished it's current context operation.
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(
                            "Dispatcher BeginInvoke " + 
                            "Setting CurrentPersonCancellable."
                        );

                        // Do this against the underlying value so 
                        //  that we don't invoke the cancellation question again.
                        _CurrentPersonCancellable = origValue;
                        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable");
                    }),
                    DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
                    null
                );

            // Exit early. 
            return;
        }

        // Normal path. Selection applied. 
        // Raise PropertyChanged on the field.
        Debug.WriteLine("Selection applied.");
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPersonCancellable");
    }
}
```

**Note:** The author uses `ContextIdle` for the `DispatcherPriority` for the action to undo the change. While fine, this is a lower priority than `Render`, which means that the change will show in the UI as the selected item momentarily changing and changing back. Using a dispatcher priority of `Normal` or even `Send` (the highest priority) preempts the display of the change. This is what I ended up doing. [See here for details about the `DispatcherPriority` enumeration.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx)

Comment: I was a said stumbler, and this is exactly what I was looking for. Only thing I'd add is that you'll need to check if `Application.Current` is null for unit tests and handle accordingly.

Comment: Right - `Application.Current` would never be null in normal operation, because the binding engine wouldn't be calling the setter if `Application()` wasn't instantiated - but you raise a good point with unit tests.

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher can be null... for some types of projects... use instead Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.

Comment: I would upvote this again if I could. This worked very well for a solution where I needed a certain set of criteria to revert a combobox selection. Using the Normal priority seems the cleaner approach.

Comment: adding a delay seems to let the ui catch up with the fact the setting of the field got bypassed.  SelectedItem="{Binding employees_vm.current_employee, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=1}"

Comment: Normal priority will still cause the UI to change selected item and then change back. Because the UI is already changing when the message box pops up.

Answer (score 14):

In .NET 4.5 they added the Delay field to the Binding. If you set the delay it will automatically wait to update so there is no need for the Dispatcher in the ViewModel. This works for validation of all Selector elements like the ListBox's and ComboBox's SelectedItem properties. The Delay is in milliseconds.

```
<ListBox 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResults, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Delay=10}" />
```

Comment: It works (ListBox) and is much simpler than the accepted answer!

Comment: Could you explain a little more clearly? Is the change will show in the UI as the selected item momentarily changing and changing back?

Comment: The delay is how long it waits before it sets the value on the binding. Any non-zero value will make the binding update asynchronous which allows the validation to work properly.

Side Note: The feature was added so that using the arrow keys in a list will wait to change the selected item until the user stops changing the selection for the specified 'Delay.'

Answer (score 7):

Got it! I am going to accept majocha's answer, because his comment underneath his answer led me to the solution.

Here is wnat I did: I created a `SelectionChanged` event handler for the ListBox in code-behind. Yes, it's ugly, but it works. The code-behind also contains a module-level variable, `m_OldSelectedIndex`, which is initialized to -1. The `SelectionChanged` handler calls the ViewModel's `Validate()` method and gets a boolean back indicating whether the Document is valid. If the Document is valid, the handler sets `m_OldSelectedIndex` to the current `ListBox.SelectedIndex` and exits. If the document is invalid, the handler resets `ListBox.SelectedIndex` to `m_OldSelectedIndex`. Here is the code for the event handler:

```
private void OnSearchResultsBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (MainViewModel) this.DataContext;
    if (viewModel.Validate() == null)
    {
        m_OldSelectedIndex = SearchResultsBox.SelectedIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        SearchResultsBox.SelectedIndex = m_OldSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Note that there is a trick to this solution: You have to use the `SelectedIndex` property; it doesn't work with the `SelectedItem` property.

Thanks for your help majocha, and hopefully this will help somebody else down the road. Like me, six months from now, when I have forgotten this solution...

Answer (score 5):

If you are serious about following MVVM and don't want any code behind, and also don't like the use of the `Dispatcher`, which frankly is not elegant either, the following solution works for me and is by far more elegant than most of the solutions provided here.

It is based on the notion that in code behind you are able to stop the selection using the `SelectionChanged` event. Well now, if this is the case, why not create a behavior for it, and associate a command with the `SelectionChanged` event. In the viewmodel you can then easily remember the previous selected index and the current selected index. The trick is to have binding to your viewmodel on `SelectedIndex` and just let that one change whenever the selection changes. But immediately after the selection really has changed, the `SelectionChanged` event fires which now is notified via the command to your viewmodel. Because you remember the previously selected index, you can validate it and if not correct, you move the selected index back to the original value.

The code for the behavior is as follows:

```
public class ListBoxSelectionChangedBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty 
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Command",
                                     typeof(ICommand),
                                     typeof(ListBoxSelectionChangedBehavior), 
                                     new PropertyMetadata());

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter",
                                      typeof(object), 
                                      typeof(ListBoxSelectionChangedBehavior),
                                      new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += ListBoxOnSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= ListBoxOnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void ListBoxOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
    }
}
```

Using it in XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox"
         Margin="2,0,2,2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Taken}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTaskIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:ListBoxSelectionChangedBehavior Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

The code that is appropriate in the viewmodel is as follows:

```
public int SelectedTaskIndex
{
    get { return _SelectedTaskIndex; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _SelectedTaskIndex, value); }
}

private void SelectionChanged()
{
    if (_OldSelectedTaskIndex >= 0 && _SelectedTaskIndex != _OldSelectedTaskIndex)
    {
        if (Taken[_OldSelectedTaskIndex].IsDirty)
        {
            SelectedTaskIndex = _OldSelectedTaskIndex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _OldSelectedTaskIndex = _SelectedTaskIndex;
    }
}

public RelayCommand SelectionChangedCommand { get; private set; }
```

In the constructor of the viewmodel:

```
SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectionChanged);
```

`RelayCommand` is part of MVVM light. Google it if you don't know it.
You need to refer to

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and hence you need to reference `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me! Can't thank you enough, I spent waay longer trying to solve this problem than I should have.

Comment: Had to add a check for null on the Command.Execute in the Behavior class but otherwise great solution. Much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I came up against this recently, and came up with a solution that works well with my MVVM, without the need for and code behind.

I created a SelectedIndex property in my model and bound the listbox SelectedIndex to it.

On the View CurrentChanging event, I do my validation, if it fails, I simply use the code

```
e.cancel = true;

//UserView is my ICollectionView that's bound to the listbox, that is currently changing
SelectedIndex = UserView.CurrentPosition;  

//Use whatever similar notification method you use
NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
```

It seems to work perfectly ATM. There may be edge cases where it doesnt, but for now, it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, the difference being that I am using `ListView` bound to an `ICollectionView` and was using `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` rather than binding the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`. This worked well for me until I wanted to cancel the `CurrentItemChanged` event of the underlying `ICollectionView`, which left the `ListView.SelectedItem` out of sync with the `ICollectionView.CurrentItem`.

The underlying problem here is keeping the view in sync with the view model. Obviously cancelling a selection change request in the view model is trivial. So we really just need a more responsive view as far as I'm concerned. I'd rather avoid putting kludges into my ViewModel to work around limitations of the `ListView` synchronization. On the other hand I'm more than happy to add some view-specific logic to my view code-behind.

So my solution was to wire my own synchronization for the ListView selection in the code-behind. Perfectly MVVM as far as I'm concerned and more robust than the default for `ListView` with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`.

Here is my code behind ... this allows changing the current item from the ViewModel as well. If the user clicks the list view and changes the selection, it will immediately change, then change back if something down-stream cancels the change (this is my desired behavior). Note I have `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` set to false on the `ListView`. Also note that I am using `async`/`await` here which plays nicely, but requires a little double-checking that when the `await` returns, we are still in the same data context.

```
void DataContextChangedHandler(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
    if (vm != null)
        vm.Items.CurrentChanged += Items_CurrentChanged;
}

private async void myListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = DataContext as ViewModel; //for closure before await
    if (vm != null)
    {
        if (myListView.SelectedIndex != vm.Items.CurrentPosition)
        {
            var changed = await vm.TrySetCurrentItemAsync(myListView.SelectedIndex);
            if (!changed && vm == DataContext)
            {
                myListView.SelectedIndex = vm.Items.CurrentPosition; //reset index
            }
        }
    }
}

void Items_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vm = DataContext as ViewModel; 
    if (vm != null)
        myListView.SelectedIndex = vm.Items.CurrentPosition;
}
```

Then in my ViewModel class I have `ICollectionView` named `Items` and this method (a simplified version is presented).

```
public async Task<bool> TrySetCurrentItemAsync(int newIndex)
{
    DataModels.BatchItem newCurrentItem = null;
    if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < Items.Count)
    {
        newCurrentItem = Items.GetItemAt(newIndex) as DataModels.BatchItem;
    }

    var closingItem = Items.CurrentItem as DataModels.BatchItem;
    if (closingItem != null)
    {
        if (newCurrentItem != null && closingItem == newCurrentItem)
            return true; //no-op change complete

        var closed = await closingItem.TryCloseAsync();

        if (!closed)
            return false; //user said don't change
    }

    Items.MoveCurrentTo(newCurrentItem);
    return true; 
}
```

The implementation of `TryCloseAsync` could use some kind of dialog service to elicit a close confirmation from the user.

Answer (score -1):

Bind `ListBox`'s property: `IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Valid, Mode=OneWay}"` where `Valid` is the view-model property with the validation algoritm. Other solutions look too far-fetched in my eyes.

When the disabled appearance is not allowed, a style could help out, but probably the disabled style is ok because changing the selection is not allowed.

Maybe in .NET version 4.5 INotifyDataErrorInfo helps, I dont'know.