# Prevent Listbox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a multi selection listbox where only certain combinations of items are permitted in selection.
How can I deny certain selection? 
The listbox is bound to view model. I thought I could do it in property setter but is doesn't work.

XAML

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" PropertyName="SelectedItems" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=TranslatorsListView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In View Model

```
public System.Collections.IList SelectedItems 
{
    get
    {
        return SelectedModels;
    }
    set 
    { 
        //what here?
    }
}
```

Edit:
I should have made clear, that I'm using multi selection. That's why I'm using interaction triggers and not just binding to SelectedItem. The linked answer is for single selection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF: Cancel a user selection in a databound ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608071/wpf-cancel-a-user-selection-in-a-databound-listbox)

Comment: The problem is I have a multiple selection listbox and cannot figure out how to modify that answer, which is for single selection. I think I'll just verify the selection when user submits the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the easiest way was to not use SelectionMode nor SelectedItem, but instead utilize the Tapped event. From this you can get the "selected item".

I then set a bound property in the ViewModel that is used by the View to change the background of the selected item in the ListView if its one that I want to select. To do this effectively your ListView needs to be tied to an ObservableCollection of ViewModels (or a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

Here's some rough code to illustrate what I mean:
In Xaml View code

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource ="{Binding Values}"
    ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    RefreshAllowed="True"
    SelectionMode="None"
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid  RowSpacing="0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Blue}" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                    <Label   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Destination}"/>
                    <Label   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In code behind:

```
private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var param = (ValueViewModel)e.Item;
    if (((SourceViewModel)BindingContext).SelectValueCommand.CanExecute(param))
    {
        ((SourceViewModel)BindingContext).SelectValueCommand.Execute(param);
    }
}
```

Then these classes used - the first is the BindingContext for the View

```
public class SourceViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SourceViewModel (List<ValueViewModel> list)
    {
        SelectValueCommand = new Command<ValueViewModel>((value) => ExecuteSelectValueCommand(value), (value)=>!IsBusy);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ValueViewModel> _values = new ObservableCollection<ValueViewModel>();
    private bool _isSelected;
    private sring _description;

    public ICommand SelectValueCommand;
    public bool IsBusy{get;set;}

    public ObservableCollection<ValueViewModel> Values 
    {
        get=>_values;
        set
        {
            _values = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Values));
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteSelectValueCommand(ValueViewModel value)
    {
        if(IsBusy) return;

        item.IsSelected = CanValueBeSelected(value);        
    }

    private bool CanValueBeSelected(ValueViewModel value)
    {
        var result = false;

        //Some logic to determine if it can be selected

        return result;
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    // ...
    #endregion  
}


public class ValueViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ValueViewModel (string description, int value)
    {
        Description = description;
        Value = value;
    }

    private int _value;
    private bool _isSelected;
    private sring _description;

    public int Value
    {
        get=>_value;
        set
        {
            _value=value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get=> _isSelected;
        set
        {
            _isSelected= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get=> _description;
        set
        {
            _description= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    // ...
    #endregion  
}
```